# I'm not able to \begin or \end{document} in my article on TexStudio

Tags: errors

This is the MWE of the code I have used (I'm using APA6 package to make an apa formatted document for my research article so have used that as the document class rather than article). When I try to compile, it keeps saying error at \begin and \end document. I'm using TexStudio on MikTex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{LDHealthResearch.bib}

\title
\shorttitle
\author{name\\affiliation \and name\\affiliation}

\begin{document} 

Text \cite and \textcite

\printbibliography
\end
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In your MWE there is only `\end`, not `\end{document}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For once, you need `\end{document}` to close your document environment. Second, you probably should have `\title` and `\shorttitle` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: And `\cite` and `\textcite` need an argument (the bibitem id).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did put in \end{document} and it still says there are errors. However, It's now building the pdf and inserting authors properly as I added the abstract having used the apa class and switched from apacite to biblatex but has decided not to insert references properly from my bibtex file. But you have solved my original problem (off to find that thread now!) thank you :)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Your code contain several errors, although one of them is not, (as suggested in the comments) place `\title` and `\shorttitle` in the preamble.

This is a minimal **working** (compilable) example:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}
\title{A} % very short tile
\shorttitle{B} % very short shorttile
\threeauthors{C}{D}{F} %three very short author names
\threeaffiliations{U. of H}{U. of I}{U. of J.}
\abstract{bla bla ...}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle

Text \textcite{IEEEexample:article_typical}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that you cannot use `\and` as in standard articles, nor mix names and affiliations, nor make the  article without abstract. You must use the specific commands of this class to make a minimal working structure. Run `texdoc apa6` to discover them. Then add/modify what you need (for example, `\threeauthors` by `\twoauthors`)  and check that still is compilable.

Comment: +1 I stand duly corrected!

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks. Is not usually explained, but `\title` could be even *before* of the  `\documentclass`.  Just remove  in my MWE the `\title{A}` and place `\title{Whatever}` in the first line.  Anyway, place `\title` and `author` after \begin{document} is always safer as far it is before `\maketitle`. The opposite is not always true (e.g, you cannot place `\threeauthors` before the preamble) .

Comment: Fran, of course, I was fooled by the lack of arguments and the non standard class and implicitly assumed those were the class' version of `\maketitle`... On second thought, I should've thought twice.  :)